# insert record into table on exception

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception, sql-insert

Here is my scenario:

I want to write a procedure in oracle, there are four tables, tab1, tab2, tab3, err. tab1 has some data in two columns `(id number, name varchar(250))`, while others are empty.

schema for tab2 is

`(id number, name varchar(50)), for tab3 (id number, name varchar(250))`.

I want to insert data from tab1 to tab2 and when there is exception like name is greater than varchar(50), it will insert into tab3 and also insert error message into err table.

So all record from tab1 should be inserted into tab2 and tab3 accordingly using exception handling.

Here is what I tried but failed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE exception_handler
IS
  vSqlErr  VARCHAR2(200) ;
  vSqlCode VARCHAR2(5) ;
  id2      NUMBER;
  name2    VARCHAR(250);
BEGIN
  INSERT ALL INTO tab3 VALUES
    (id, name
    )
  SELECT * FROM tab1 t;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES
    (id, name
    );
  vSqlErr  := SUBSTR(sqlerrm, 1, 200) ;
  vSqlCode := SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 5) ;
  INSERT INTO err VALUES
    (vSqlErr, vSqlCode
    ) ;
  COMMIT ;
  RAISE;
END;
```

Comment: I'm fresh with database, so want someone do for me,

Comment: **CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
exception_handler
IS
 
  vSqlErr          Varchar2(200) ;
  vSqlCode         Varchar2(5) ;
  id2               number;
  name2             varchar(250);
BEGIN
  insert all
  into tab3 values (id, name)
  select * from tab1 t;

  EXCEPTION
    
    WHEN Others THEN      
     insert into tab2 values(id, name);
      
      vSqlErr := substr(sqlerrm, 1, 200) ;
      vSqlCode := substr(sqlcode, 1, 5) ;
      
    insert into err values(vSqlErr, vSqlCode) ;
    

      Commit ;
RAISE;
end;**

Comment: I have edited your question. And, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a simple demonstration based on your inputs in the question. Better go for **BULK** processing and **SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS**. [And don't use WHEN OTHERS blindly](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/).

Let's say you have an `EMP` table, and you have a `check constraint` on employee name as not more than 5 characters. There is an `EMP_ERR` table to **log the error values and error message**. Lets see a test case:

```
SQL> DROP TABLE emp_new PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE emp_new AS
  2  SELECT * FROM emp WHERE 1 =2;

Table created.

SQL> ALTER TABLE emp_new ADD CONSTRAINT check_ename CHECK(LENGTH(ename)<=5);

Table altered.

SQL> DROP TABLE emp_err PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE emp_err
  2    (
  3      empno   NUMBER,
  4      ename   VARCHAR2(100),
  5      err_msg VARCHAR2(250)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE p
  3    (
  4      v_empno NUMBER,
  5      v_ename VARCHAR2
  6    )
  7  IS
  8    vSqlErr  VARCHAR2(200) ;
  9    vSqlCode VARCHAR2(5) ;
 10    empno2   NUMBER;
 11    ename2   VARCHAR2(250);
 12  BEGIN
 13    INSERT INTO emp_new
 14      (empno, ename
 15      ) VALUES
 16      (v_empno, v_ename
 17      );
 18    COMMIT;
 19  EXCEPTION
 20  WHEN OTHERS THEN
 21    vSqlErr  := SUBSTR(sqlerrm, 1, 200) ;
 22    vSqlCode := SUBSTR(SQLCODE, 1, 5) ;
 23    INSERT
 24    INTO emp_err
 25      (
 26        empno,
 27        ename,
 28        err_msg
 29      )
 30      VALUES
 31      (
 32        v_empno,
 33        v_ename,
 34        vSqlErr
 35        ||' - '
 36        ||vSqlCode
 37      );
 38    COMMIT ;
 39    raise;
 40  END;
 41  /

Procedure created.
```

Lets execute the procure with ename value as more than 5 characters, so that it raises an error, and we expect a row to be inserted into the `emp_err` table.

```
SQL> exec p(1, 'abcdef');
BEGIN p(1, 'abcdef'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CHECK_ENAME) violated
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P", line 38
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

So, the error is raised. Lets see if it is logged in the error table.

```
SQL> column ename format a10
SQL> column err_msg format a100
SQL> set linesize 150

SQL> select * from emp_err;

     EMPNO ENAME      ERR_MSG
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 abcdef     ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CHECK_ENAME) violated - -2290

SQL>
```

We have the error details logged.

Comment: Kumar as I also want to insert records into 3rd table when an exception is raised,

Comment: So???? What stops you from doing that? I have given you a complete answer. All you need to do is add another insert statement, so simple. Do you want me to write the code for you? You can't expect somebody to do your homework. I have also edited your question for you. Formatted your code, added relevant tags. What else do you expect? You have a complete answer with a working test case. Please mark it as answered if it has helped you.

Comment: how to add another insert statement after exception raised, insert all record from table1 to table2 and the record which are greater than varchar(50) insert those all to table3

Comment: How did I add at line 24 in my code? Did you even try before asking me?

Comment: my code also inserting error into table, but I'm confused at how to insert record into 3rd table when exception raised, (mean the records which are not inserted into table2 bcoz larger size should be inserted into table3)

Comment: also i need to insertion done on select record from table1 and insert into table2 when value is greater than varchar(5) than insert into table 3 for all record in table1

Comment: For values more than length 5 character, create a check constraint. Just like I did in the example. So,that when it errors out, you will insert those error records into another table.